# Skype Bot Rest API, 403 The bot is not allowed to perform the requested operation

Tags: botframework, http-status-code-403, skype

So I used an account and message my skype bot.

Received Message: {"text":"test","type":"message","timestamp":"2017-11-15T21:52:10.379Z","id":"1510782730376","channelId":"skype","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/","from":{"id":"29:1tJkKyeNp1o5xbMfK9hxF_U2s7huwsAKi4LMD0kOJbkg"},"conversation":{"id":"29:1tJkKyeNp1o5xbMfK9hxF_U2s7huwsAKi4LMD0kOJbkg"},"recipient":{"id":"28:8a75f591-62bf-422b-be6c-4b4b8bd1a576","name":"SKYPE_BOT"},"entities":[{"locale":"ru-RU","country":"RU","platform":"Windows","type":"clientInfo"}],"channelData":{"text":"test"}}

Sending 'POST' request to URL : https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/29:1tJkKyeNp1o5xbMfK9hxF_U2s7huwsAKi4LMD0kOJbkg/activities/1510782730376
Post parameters : {"replyToId":"1510782730376","recipient":{"id":"29:1tJkKyeNp1o5xbMfK9hxF_U2s7huwsAKi4LMD0kOJbkg"},"from":{"name":"SKYPE_BOT","id":"28:8a75f591-62bf-422b-be6c-4b4b8bd1a576"},"text":"Hello, test","type":"message","locale":"ru","conversation":{"id":"29:1tJkKyeNp1o5xbMfK9hxF_U2s7huwsAKi4LMD0kOJbkg"}}

Response Code : 403 Response message: Forbidden

403     The bot is not allowed to perform the requested operation.

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> To communicate with the Bot Connector service, you must specify an
>   access token in the Authorization header of each API request, using
>   this format:
>
> Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication#bot-to-connector

Comment: This is my header:

{Authorization=Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC............, Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8}

Comment: Please, any ideas

Comment: @FrankSinatra Sorry, I don't have any suggestions based on what information is provided.  Can you share your bots code somewhere?

Comment: did it, shared on git. i've send you the link via e-mail